# aws beanstalk cloudformation add CPUCreditBalance alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation, monitoring

I am trying to add a CPUCreditBalance AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm to the EBN application using cloudformation. it is similar to the picture but using cloudformation [image]

EC2 instances and the autoscalinggroup is created by the cloudformation as well. so i dont know how to get either InscanceId or AutoScalingGroupName to place it in this code

```
CPUCreditBalanceAlarm:
Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
Properties:
  AlarmDescription: Warning alarm when EC2 rans out of credit
  MetricName: CPUCreditBalance
  Namespace: AWS/EC2
  Period: 300
  Statistic: Average
  ComparisonOperator: LessThanThreshold
  Threshold: 1
  EvaluationPeriods: 2
  DatapointsToAlarm: 2
  TreatMissingData: breaching
  Dimensions:
    - Name: AutoScalingGroupName
      Value: XXXXXXXX
  AlarmActions:
    - !Ref SnsAlarmWarning
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your `AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup` defined in the same template as the alarm, then you can just use `Ref` to get ASG [name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#aws-properties-as-group-return-values):

```
  Dimensions:
    - Name: AutoScalingGroupName
      Value: !Ref AWSEBAutoScalingGroup
  AlarmActions:
    - !Ref SnsAlarmWarning
```

Names of resources created by EB are listed in:

- [Modifying the resources that Elastic Beanstalk creates for your environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-format-resources-eb.html)

Comment: no, the AutoScalingGroupName is created automatically when running the script for the beanstalk

Comment: or is there away to attache AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup resource to Beanstalk in cloudformation?

Comment: @AshrafAlKibsi Yes, I updated the answer. The ASG created by EB is `AWSEBAutoScalingGroup`.

Comment: it didn't work shows that AWSEBAutoScalingGroup is undefined :(

Comment: @AshrafAlKibsi You must be doing something wrong. Can you provide your `resources` section from `.ebextensions`?

Comment: it is a yaml file uploaded to cloudformation.  not using .ebextensions

Comment: @AshrafAlKibsi Maybe you can update your question and explaiin exactly what you are doing. When you work with EB, your custom CFN resources should be defined in `resource` section as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html). This includes `Outputs` if you want to export something from the EB stack to be used in different stacks.